# Select books having specified authors

Tags: sql

I have `Book` and `Author` tables. `Book` have many `Author`s (I know that it should be many-to-many it's just for the sake of this example).

How do I select all books that have been written by authors: X **and** by Y in one sql query?

**EDIT**

Number of authors can be variable - 3, 5 or more authors.

I can't figure it out now (I've tried to do `JOIN`s and sub-queries).

`SELECT * FROM book ...`?

Comment: Please, show us your database schema.

Comment: Also, what database are you using? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This is general sql question but it can be in PostgreSQL (I'm using it).

Comment: See my answer. To have 3,5 authors you must change `IN` and `HAVING` clauses only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  B.Name
FROM Books B
  JOIN Authors A
    ON B.AuthorID = A.ID
WHERE A.Name IN ('X', 'Y')
GROUP BY B.Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT A.ID) = 2
```

Comment: You can omit `DISTINCT`, it just need if you have duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1):

You can just double join the authors table.

```
SELECT Book.* from Book 
    JOIN Author author1 
        ON author1.book_id = Book.id AND author1.author_name = 'Some Name'
    JOIN Author author2
        ON author2.book_id = Book.id AND author1.author_name = 'Some Other Name'
GROUP BY Book.id
```

The JOINs ensure that only books with Both authors are returned, and the GROUP BY just makes the result set only contain unique entries.

It's worth noting by the way that this query will bring back books that have *at least* the two authors specified. For example, if you want books only by Smith and Jones, and not by Smith, Jones and Martin, this query will not do that. This query will pull back books that have *at least* Smith and Jones.

Comment: So if I had to create query with many authors (3, 5 or more) I should include new `JOIN ON` clause...?

Comment: @Xeon That would work, but hmm, it wouldn't be very scalable unless the RDBMS optimizes the hell out of it. Let me think for a minute.

Comment: @Xeon at the moment, I can't think of a relatively pleasant way to scale the JOINs like this to an arbitrary level. I would be tempted to go with Hamlet Hakobyan's approach in that situation (The performance of his approach is going to degrade very quickly if the number of books is large though :/). I'm quite intrigued by this now though, so when I have a chance later, I'm going to look into this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

select * from book where author=.... ?

I found it hard to understand your structure but this seems like the best way?

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your Author table has a Book ID (as this would give many author to one book).

```
SELECT * from Books Where ID IN
(SELECT BookID from Author A 
 JOIN Author B on A.BookID = B.BookID and A.ID <> B.ID 
 WHERE A.ID IN ('X', 'Y') AND B.ID IN ('X','Y'))
```

EDIT: Hamlet's answer is much better (scaleable).